# How to update the StackNavigator (add screens) after auth

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I am working on a application which have two types of users, user and admin, I want to import only those screens which are related to userType after authentication, for now I am importing all screens but I want to do it in this way, import only login screen on stack-navigator and after authentication push the screens related to the userType.

Comment: can you show your code snippet that what are you doing right now?

Comment: As per your question I can only suggest this: please make two different stack navigator as role base and call as per your need

Comment: @AndroidTeam but login is common for both that will come before the decision for role base